# AMP page is ok but is not visible when clicked (empty)

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP page for my index.html and it has passed all the validation test, and it has been successfully indexed, as resulting in the search console. It also appears with the lightning icon in the google smartphone SERP, but when I click on the link, it appears as blank and empty. 
If you want more info please visit: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.studiopsicologiaabruzzo.it/amp/index.amp.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that the cached version of your website has everything wrapped inside `<amp-sidebar>`. I can see that this is no longer the case on your canonical page, so it renders correctly now, but the AMP cache hasn't yet picked up this change.

You have two options:

1. Wait until the AMP cache updates. It respects `max-age` set by your page, which appears to be 7 days, so this is the longest you'd need to wait (from the moment the page was originally cached).
2. Follow the steps outlined in [Update AMP Content](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache) to flush the currently cached version of your page.